# Setting session in Zend Registry Or Create each time new instance of session?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am little confuse. I want to know what is the best solution. Should I have to initiate session in bootstrap like:

```
protected function _initSession()
{
    Zend_Session::start();
    $session = new Zend_Session_Namespace() ; 
    Zend_Registry::set("session", $session) ; 
}
```

And to call session object in controller like

```
    $session = Zend_Registry::get("session") ;
```

Or Another option is to create session object each time I need in the controller like

```
    $session = new Zend_Session_Namespace();
```

I want to know what is the difference? is there any memory issue or performance issue like What I am asuming When I create object each time it needs some space in memory :P and Zend_Registry creates object only once in memory :D What you think ?

Thanks!
Best Regards

Answer (score 1):

**Zend_Registry** is used to store objects/values for the current request. In short, anything that you commit to Registry in index.php can be accessed from other controllers/actions (because EVERY request is first routed to the index.php bootstrapper via the .htaccess file). Config parameters and db parameters are generally prepped for global use using the Zend_Registry object.

**Zend_Session_Namespace** actually uses PHP sessions. Data stored using Zend_Session can be accessed in different/all pages. So, if you want to create a variable named ‘UserRole’ in the /auth/login script and want it to be accessible in /auth/redirect, you would use Zend_Session.

***For Example***

if you have a DB object stored in the registry, and when you are access a page say login page, this particular DB object will be accessible to any of the files used in that page (to construct), meaning global access (same keyword in PHP [Scope Variable](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#language.variables.scope.global)).

Whereas, Session scope means you can access anywhere on any page until you close your browser (until your session get’s destroyed).

**EDIT**

**Zend_Session** is for working with the session extension in PHP.This would be for tracking loggin in user(s), etc.

**Zend_Registry** is used to store objects / resources / etc in at runtime. The idea is that you want to use maybe 1 config object, or 1 database throughout your entire application.  So what you would do, when you create these objects, you would assign them to the registry.

It is depends on your Requirement, in which type you want to utilize both of them.

I Hope it is very clear now.

Comment: I know Zend_Registry have global scope and Zend_Session uses php session. But the question is when I create new instance of class defiantly it get some space in memory. So I am assuming storing session object in Zend_Registry is better option? What you think?

Answer (score 0):

The difference is as you described: distinct instances - in the limited scope in which you have described them - would be slightly wasteful: they both access the same underlying session storage, so why consume resources instantiating and loading a second instance into memory?